# Android volley listview not showing

Tags: android, json, listview, android-volley

Issue: Android volley listview not showing.

Description: trying to get the Json data in listview format, in logcat it is showing, even i am able to parse it properly.
but when i try to run it in Fragment it doesnot display anything only 
this error.

W/AbsListView: Intent to operate on non-exist data, childcount=0, mFirstPosition=0, mItemCount=0, adapter count=0, mAdapter=com.brillmindz.roomshare.CustomListAdapter@3fbf203f, action=0, mActivePointerId=0, mScrollY=0, this=android.widget.ListView{1752f18f V.ED.VC. ........ 0,0-540,691 #7f0d004c app:id/homelistView}

here's the code OF

HomepageFragment

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, container, false);

   // usersList = new ArrayList<String>();


    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.homelistView);

    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this,hotelLists);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());

    // Showing progress dialog before making http request

    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");

    pDialog.show();


    final StringRequest jsonObjReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url_shareroom, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
 public void onResponse(String response) {

            Log.d(TAG, response);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            HotelList hotelList = new HotelList();

          //  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                String hotelsDetailsArray = jsonObject.getString("hotelsDetails");
                Log.d("Hotel name : ", hotelsDetailsArray);
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(hotelsDetailsArray);
                for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length();i++) {
                    JSONObject mJsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String hotelName  = mJsonObject.getString("hotel_name");
                    Log.d("Hotel name : ", hotelName);
                    String city  = mJsonObject.getString("city");
                    Log.d("City : ", city);
                    String state  = mJsonObject.getString("state");
                    Log.d("State : ", state);
                    String country  = mJsonObject.getString("country");
                    Log.d("Country : ", country);
                    String address  = mJsonObject.getString("address");
                    Log.d("Address : ", address);
                    String list_title  = mJsonObject.getString("list_title");
                    Log.d("list_title : ", list_title);
                    String check_in_date  = mJsonObject.getString("check_in_date");
                    Log.d("check_in_date : ", check_in_date);
                    String check_out_date  = mJsonObject.getString("check_out_date");
                    Log.d("check_out_date : ", check_out_date);
                    String rate  = mJsonObject.getString("rate");
                    Log.d("rate : ", rate);
                    String created  = mJsonObject.getString("created");
                    Log.d("created : ", created);
                    String created_time  = mJsonObject.getString("created_time");
                    Log.d("created_time : ", created_time);
                    String matching_percentage  = mJsonObject.getString("matching_percentage");
                    Log.d("matching_percentage : ", matching_percentage);
                    String star_rating  = mJsonObject.getString("star_rating");
                    Log.d("star_rating : ", star_rating);
                    String reviews  = mJsonObject.getString("reviews");
                    Log.d("reviews : ", reviews);

               hotelLists.add(hotelList);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

    **      adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this,hotelLists);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();** 

        }

 }

    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override

                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

               /*     Log.e("Error Response", error.toString());*/

                    Log.e(TAG, "Volley Error: " + error.getMessage());

                    // 

Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            }) {

        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {

            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            params.put("user_id", "80");

            return params;

        }

    };

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);

    return rootView;


}



@Override

public void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();

    hidePDialog();

}

private void hidePDialog() {

    if (pDialog != null) {

        pDialog.dismiss();

        pDialog = null;

    }

}


}
```

---

Custom list adapter

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private HomePageFragment homePageFragment;

Context mycontext;

private LayoutInflater inflater;

private List<HotelList> hotelItems;

ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

public CustomListAdapter(HomePageFragment hpfragment, List<HotelList> hotelItems) {

    this.homePageFragment = hpfragment;

    this.hotelItems = hotelItems;

}


@Override

public int getCount() {

    return hotelItems.size();

}


@Override

public Object getItem(int location) {

    return hotelItems.get(location);

}


@Override

public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position;

}


@Override

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mycontext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    }

   /* if (imageLoader == null)

        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);*/

    TextView hotel_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.hotel_name);

    TextView city = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.city);

    TextView state = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.state);

    TextView amenities =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.amenities);

    TextView country = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.country);

    // getting data for the row
    HotelList m = hotelItems.get(position);



    hotel_name.setText(m.getHotel_name());

Log.e("Hotelname", m.getHotel_name());

    city.setText(m.getCity());

    Log.e("city", m.getCity());

    amenities.setText(m.getAmenities());

    Log.e("amenities", m.getAmenities());

    state.setText(m.getState());

    Log.e("state", m.getState());

    country.setText(m.getCountry());

    Log.e("country", m.getCountry());

    return convertView;
}

}
```

---

Hotel List

```
public class HotelList {

private String
        hotel_name,
        rate,
        city,
        state,
        country,
        address,
        list_title,
        check_in_date,
        check_out_date,
        amenities,
        created,
        created_time,
        match_percentage,
        star_rating,
        reviews;


private String user_Id;


public HotelList() {
}

public HotelList(String hotel_name, String city, String state, String country,
                 String address, String list_title, String check_in_date, String amenities,
                 String check_out_date, String created, String created_time, String match_percentage, String star_rating, String reviews
) {
    this.hotel_name= hotel_name;
    this.city = city;
    this.amenities= amenities;
    this.state = state;
    this.country= country;
    this.address= address;
    this.list_title = list_title;
    this.check_in_date= check_in_date;
    this.check_out_date= check_out_date;
    this.created =created;
    this.rate= rate;
    this.created_time= created_time;
    this.match_percentage= match_percentage;
    this.star_rating = star_rating;
    this.reviews= reviews;
}




//STRING

private String created() {
    return created;
}

private String created_time() {
    return created_time;
}

private String star_rating() {
    return star_rating;
}

private String match_percentage() {
    return match_percentage;
}

private String reviews() {
    return reviews;
}
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public String getState() {
    return state;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public String getHotel_name() {
    return hotel_name;
}

public String getList_title() {
    return list_title;
}

private String check_out_date() {
    return check_out_date;
}

private String check_in_date() {
    return check_in_date;
}

private String list_title() {
    return list_title;
}

private String address() {
    return address;
}

private String hotel_name() {
    return hotel_name;
}

public String getCheck_in_date() {
    return check_in_date;
}

public String getCheck_out_date() {
    return check_out_date;
}

private String country() {
    return country;
}

private String state() {
    return state;
}

private String city() {
    return city;
}

public String getAmenities() {
    return amenities;
}

public String getRate() {
    return rate;
}

//SETTER
public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}

public void setHotel_name(String hotel_name) {
    this.hotel_name = hotel_name;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public void setList_title(String list_title) {
    this.list_title = list_title;
}

public void setCheck_in_date(String check_in_date) {
    this.check_in_date = check_in_date;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}

public void setCheck_out_date(String check_out_date) {
    this.check_out_date = check_out_date;
}

public void setAmenities(String amenities) {
    this.amenities = amenities;
}

public void setUser_Id(String user_Id) {
    this.user_Id = user_Id;
}

public void setGenre(ArrayList<String> genre) {
}


public String getCreated_time() {
    return created_time;
}

public String getMatch_percentage() {
    return match_percentage;
}

public String getStar_rating() {
    return star_rating;
}

public String getReviews() {
    return reviews;
}
}
```

---

MY JSON response

{
    "success": "1",
    "hotelsDetails": [{
        "id": "1",
        "hotel_name": "The Ritz-Carlton New York, Central Park",
        "city": "new york",
        "amenities": "",
        "state": "Alaska",
        "country": "United States",
        "address": "50 Central Park S New York 10019",
        "list_title": "Ritz-Carlton New York",
        "check_in_date": "2016-03-17",
        "check_out_date": "2016-03-21",
        "rate": "100",
        "created": "2016-02-11",
        "created_time": "00:00:00",
        "matching_percentage": "73",
        "star_rating": "3",
        "reviews": "15"
    }, {
        "id": "2",

where i am getting wrong.?

Comment: Future note: Create a [mcve]. Don't just dump a large block of code

Comment: Thank you, will keep in mind, but have to post large blocks so that person can get idea to find problem.

Comment: I know, but you included many Log statements in your question and if you used Gson, then your JSON parsing would be much shorter

Answer (score 0):

you don't parse anything on volley response
you should parse response and add it to your adapter in this part

```
@Override

        public void onResponse(String response) {

            Log.d(TAG, response);
            //parse data and add to adapter
            pDialog.dismiss();
}
```

in addition , where is your list initial before volley response?

and your response is jsonobject , use JsonRequest instead StringRequest

Comment: Big Thanks to you for it, but i didnt get it what 'list initial'? and i did  it like in Homepage fragment( RESPONSE UPDATED). please have a look

Comment: how to add jsonObject request inside of string request? still not showing any list.. where am i getting wrong?

Comment: i types wrong .  i mean use JSONRequest instead StringRequest

Comment: send your api for me to check volley request

Comment: here's API(POST) userid: 80(if showing invalid request) http://roomshare.brillmindz.org/apis/shareroom

Answer (score 0):

You are setting an empty list in the adapter and when you are getting the data from back-end and update the list with data, you are not updating the adapter with new data in the list. Just call `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()` after updating your list with the data. That should make it work.

Comment: where are you adding that? Can you update you code in the question?

Comment: Updated the Homepagefragment, code added just next to json exception. please have a look

Comment: now getting nullpointerexception at  @Override
    public int getCount() {
   -->     return hotelItems.size();
    }

Answer (score 0):

After you finish parsing the `JSON`, ie: After the `try/catch` block, execute the following.

```
adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this,newHotelLists);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
```

`newHotelsList` is the new list of hotels that you download.

Comment: First cast it into a BaseAdapter. E.g:

adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this,newHotelLists);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

//Now cast the adapter to a BaseAdapter
BaseAdapter baseAdapter = (BaseAdapter)adapter;
baseAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();

It should work now.

Comment: in log cat: adapter = 'this' is not available
hotelLists = 'this' is not available
listView = 'this' is not available
hotelList = {HotelList@4148} 
response = {String@4147} "{"success":"1"....":"United St"
this = {HomePageFragment$1@4142}

Comment: "this" is not available. i guess adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this,newHotelLists); we have to replace this with context or something. what to do?

Comment: Use HomePageFragment.this

Comment: still no luck! still getting: Intent to operate on non-exist data, childcount=0, mFirstPosition=0,